# Using USB ethernet to share internet to router

Tags: connection-sharing

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.02 on a Raspberry Pi 4. I get my main internet from Starlink but because I'm in the forest, I have frequent obstructions. To deal with the obstructions, I tether my android via usb and use speedify to create a more stable connection.

I'd like to share this stable connection to my wireless router (I don't use Starlink's wireless feature), so I bought a usb to ethernet adapter. I thought I'd be able to use Eth0 to connect to starlink and set by USB to ethernet adapter IPv4 to "share to other computers" and this would share my internet from the Eth0 to the USB to ethernet adapter. However, when plugged into the router, it doesn't seem to get internet.

I plugged my VOIP phone into the USB to ethernet adapter and all it says is "Checking DNS."

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (Essentially I'm trying to share my eth0 internet to a USB to ethernet adapter; after I get that working I'll tackle adding the tethered phone).